# Find the nearest key in dictionary grid

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose you have a big grid represented by a dictionary. At some coordinates there are "players" while the other coordinates are empty. The dictionary

`d = {(500,100): "player1", (480, 230): "player"}`

(these are the locations of the players in the grid).

Now if you have a coordinate of lets say (500, 90), which of the two players are the closest? I understand that the Pythagorean theorem will have to be implemented in some way in order to solve this, but I don't understand how to implement it in a function.
This is the farthest I've come:

```
d = {(500,100): "player1", (480, 230): "player"}
def nearest_player(grid, x-cor, y-cor):
'''print out (500,100) as the answer'''
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1: Brute force**

A brute force solution could be to search through all players and pick up the closest one:

```py
# I renamed x-cor to x, and y-cor to y since these were not valid python names
def nearest_player(grid, x, y):
    best_distance = float('inf')
    best_player = None

    for pos, player in grid.items():
        # I actually use squared distance since this is 
        # equivalent to the "real" distance
        distance = (pos - x) ** 2 + (pos - y) ** 2

        if distance < best_distance:
            best_distance = distance
            best_player = player

    return best_player
```

**Option 2**

A more elegant way would be the following:

```py
def nearest_player(grid, x, y):
    distances = [(pos - x) ** 2 + (pos - y) ** 2 for pos in grid]
    return grid.values()[distances.index(min(distances))]
```

What am I doing here?

First, you compute all distances:

```py
distances = [(pos - x) ** 2 + (pos - y) ** 2 for pos in grid]
```

This yields an array with all distances.
Then I compute the index of its minimum:

```py
distances.index(min(distances))
```

which given to the list of values of your `grid` gives the player:

```py
grid.values()[distances.index(min(distances))]
```

and voila :)

**Side note: Taking it one step further**

Just for the sake of brain use (I don't know if this is proper english).
Let's imagine your actual keys are not coordinates, but something different (a `str` and you need to compute [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)). You could do the following:

```py
def nearest(data, item, d):
    distances = [d(item, i) for i in data]
    return data.values()[distances.index(min(distances))]
```

and you actually need to provide a function `d` (for distance), that computes the distance between two items. And that's it.

In your current case, `d` would be:

```py
def euclidean_distance(x, y):
    return sum((x[i] - y[i]) ** 2 for i in range(0, len(x)))
```

if you provide `x` and `y` as either a `tuple` or a `list`.

Comment: I think I find the first solution slightly more elegant. Yes it has a loop, but not keeping the index and then having to search for it is inefficient.

Comment: Well, agree and disagree :-p . I'd say it's more compact (this is what I meant by elegant). However, it's less optimal.

Comment: Glad to hear you've surmounted this herculean programming challenge, "Zeus".

Comment: Of course! I'm a programming god as you might have noticed. - @Denziloe

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy norm:

```
In[9] newd = {np.linalg.norm(np.array(i)-np.array(c)):v for i, v in d.items()}

In [10]: newd
Out[10]: {10.0: 'player1', 141.4213562373095: 'player'}

In [12]: newd[min(newd)]
Out[12]: 'player1'
```

Comment: `newd[min(newd)]` is clever.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other solutions, just factored a bit differently.

```
d = {(500,100): "player1", (480, 230): "player2"}

target_location = (500, 90)

def get_square_distance(v1, v2):
    return sum((x1 - x2)**2 for x1, x2 in zip(v1, v2))

smallest_square_distance = float('inf')

for player_location, player in d.items():
    square_distance = get_square_distance(player_location, target_location)
    if square_distance < smallest_square_distance:
        closest_player = player
        smallest_square_distance = square_distance

print(closest_player)
Out: 'player1'
```

I'm not sure a dictionary is the best data structure for your purposes. A list of lists would be more natural.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can do `argmin` in pure Python with `min(iterable, key=f)`, where `f` is the function to be minimised. So:

```
d = {(500,100): "player1", (480, 230): "player2"}

target_location = (500, 90)

def square_distance(v1, v2):
    return sum((x1 - x2)**2 for x1, x2 in zip(v1, v2))

nearest_location = min(d, key=lambda location: square_distance(location, target_location))
nearest_player = d[nearest_location]
```